# AngularJS, open preview of a PDF from buffer response

Tags: angularjs, pdf, buffer

I'm using `NodeJS 16.4` and `AngularJS 1.5.8`. I'm also using `JSReport` ([JSReport](https://jsreport.net/)) with NodeJS integration. 
This is my task: i need to create a pdf through a template with JSReport. I did it and the function is generating a `buffer response`:

```
router.post('/queryreport/certificationAdvancement', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const data = req.body.data;
        var inspectionType = '';

        if(data.inspection == 12) inspectionType = 'Ispezioni Visive';
        else inspectionType = `Ispezioni ${data.supervision_number}^ Sorveglianza`;

        const title = 'Stato Avanzamento delle Certificazioni';
        const subtitle = `${inspectionType} - Anno ${data.year}`;

        //Header del Report
        const header = await get_queryReport_header(data.dealer, title, subtitle);
        //Footer del Report
        const footer = await get_footer(title);
        //Dataset del Report
        const dataset = await get_certificationAdvancement_dataset(data);

        //Costruzione del Report tramite JSReport
        const report = await jsreport.render({
            template: {name: 'certificationAdvancement'},
            data: {header: header, dataset: dataset, footer: footer}
        })

        const buffer_report = await report.body();
        console.log(buffer_report);

        res.contentType('application/pdf');
        res.send(buffer_report);

    }
    catch (error) {
        global.loggerWinston.error(commons.sios_loggerWinstonError(error, 'SIOS'));
        return commons.showerror(error, res);
    }
});
```

The `console.log(buffer_report)` has the form of a buffer:
`<Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 36 0a 25 ff ff ff ff 0a 0a 34 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0a 3c 3c 0a 09 2f 63 61 20 31 0a 09 2f 42 4d 20 2f 4e 6f 72 6d 61 6c 0a 3e 3e 0a ... 38478 more bytes>`

I'm trying to send it back to front end (angularJS) and preview the pdf file inside the browser, possibly in a new tab. I've tried many solutions but it seems nothing's working

```
$scope.download_jsreport = function () {
    var data = {year: $scope.Year, dealer: $scope.Dealer, inspection: parseInt($scope.Inspection)};
    if($scope.numSorv) data.supervision_number = $scope.numSorv;

    /*
    jsreportService.certificationAdvancement.post is the service used to call the function
    I could write it through a $http.post like this
    
    $http.post('/api/jsreport/queryreport/certificationAdvancement', {data: data})
    .then(function(result) {
    
    });
    
    */
    
    //$window.open(jsreportService.certificationAdvancement.post({data: data}), '_blank');

    jsreportService.certificationAdvancement.post({data: data}, function (result) {
        /* var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," +  encodeURIComponent(result.report);
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.download = result.filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

        var a_link = document.createElement('a');
        a_link.href = 'data: application/octet-stream; base64, ' + result.buffer_report.data;
        a_link.download = 'certificationAdvancement.pdf';
        a_link.click(); */
    });
}
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT:
based on Michael G.'s answer, I managed to resolve it.

This is the final part of the server-side call, when the pdf is already done (the previous part remained the same)

```
//Costruzione del Report tramite JSReport
const report = await jsreport.render({
    template: {name: 'certificationAdvancement'},
    data: {header: header, dataset: dataset, footer: footer}
});

const resultReport = await report.body();
return res.send(Buffer.from(resultReport).toJSON());
```

And the controller part became (when the call is done):

```
const reportBuffer = new Uint8Array(result.data);
const file = new Blob([reportBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

const fileName = 'file.pdf';
var a_link = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a_link);
a_link.style = 'display: none';
a_link.href = fileURL;
a_link.download = fileName;
a_link.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been something I've been trying to do all week.  This is the solution I've found that seems to work the way it should:
When returning the report buffer data from Express to AngularJS I convert the buffer to JSON as:

```
res.send(Buffer.from(report.content).toJSON());
```

On the Express side, I convert the .data from the JSON formatted buffer to an Uint8Array:

```
let reportBuff = new Uint8Array(reportOutput.data);
let pageData = new Blob([reportBuff], {type: 'application/pdf'} );
this.$window.open(URL.createObjectURL(pageData));
```

In this case, PDF, but should work for HTML as well.

Comment: Sorry if I answer only now, but I had other things too.
Helped by your answer, I managed to do it, I will edit my question with the solution, thank you!